# How to check if Dag is running or not using Python REST API?

Tags: python, airflow

I have dag id stored in variable in python code. I want to know if that dag is in running state or not. How can i know that using REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this end point:

```
GET /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs
```

to get a list of all dag runs and their statuses for example look at my output:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/my_dag_id/dag_runs
[
    {
        "dag_id": "my_dag_id",
        "dag_run_url": "/admin/airflow/graph?dag_id=my_dag_id&execution_date=2020-11-04+00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00",
        "execution_date": "2020-11-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "id": 62,
        "run_id": "scheduled__2020-11-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-11-05T14:05:36.902918+00:00",
        "state": "running"
    },
    {
        "dag_id": "my_dag_id",
        "dag_run_url": "/admin/airflow/graph?dag_id=my_dag_id&execution_date=2020-11-05+14%3A05%3A32.496146%2B00%3A00",
        "execution_date": "2020-11-05T14:05:32.496146+00:00",
        "id": 61,
        "run_id": "manual__2020-11-05T14:05:32.496146+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-11-05T14:05:32.505224+00:00",
        "state": "running"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks hatef Alipoor, the problem is , api response is not in list format, but in string format. So it very difficult and time consuming to parse that string and get value for specific Dag.  ( i am using python )

Comment: you're welcome, the response is in json format, you can use libraries for working with json format and the libraries do those stuff for you

Comment: import json
 s = '[{"name":"value"}, {"name1":"value1"}]'
 d = json.loads(s)
d[0]
>> {'name': 'value'}

Comment: d[0] >> {'name': 'value'}    , may i know what does it mean?

Comment: you can access the first element in the list and it is a dictionary and you can access 'state' from there

Comment: Ohkk... i think i will need to match my dag_id with all elements in list. because i want state for specific dag_id

Comment: I know, it is the dag runs info for your specific dag_id

Comment: Thanks hatef Alipoor, it solved my issue : )

Is there any API available to get names off all tasks in specific dag? actually i could not find it in airflow documentation.

Comment: yw, @Dhairyaa I think your find this useful https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin#list_tasks