# How to get the status of a dag run in Cloud Composer as soon as the run is complete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to trigger all the dags present on Cloud composer using a bash script. I am able to run the dags successfully, but is there a way to get the status of the dag as soon as the dag run is completed. I have checked the rest APIs available [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) and there is no specific API that will run the dag and wait for its execution to complete and give us the status of the dag.

Is there any way to achieve this ??

Note: I was thinking of using a for loop after the command I have used to execute the dag to check the status of the dag periodically as I know the max time my dags will take. But looking for a generic solution.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Hi @SayanBhattacharya, thank you for the answer. This is the one I have already tried and I have also mentioned this idea in the question of using a for loop with some delay so that I will get the status of the dag using the same script without having to run another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such an API available which will execute and give you the status of the DAG after execution. Once you execute the DAG you need to manually check the status.
You can do this 2 ways.

1. Calling the [Get a DAG run](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag_run) Airflow rest API and from the JSON response you can check the status(i.e `state` key). [You can check out this stack thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698375/how-to-check-if-dag-is-running-or-not-using-python-rest-api)
2. From [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run) / [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#) commands you can use [**dags state**](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#state) or [**dag list-runs**](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list-runs) command to fetch the status of A DAG.
   Eg in GCP environment :

```
gcloud composer environments run environment_name --location 'us-central1' dags state -- my_dag_id -- execution_date
```

As there are no generic API / CLI Commands available, you need to  check the status of a DAG continuously programmatically until it returns a run status.